# converting only parts of a subversion repository from git

Tags: svn, git

I have an old Subversion repository with lots of my private projects. Parts of it where converted from an old CVS repository some years ago (with cvs2svn or similar). Its current structure looks like this:

- trunk

  - latex
  - java

    - awt-doku
    - pps

      - build.xml
      - src

        - ant
        - de

          - dclj
          - faq
          - paul

            - (about 20 other packages)
            - **ltxdoclet**

              - (some java files)
  - lua
  - (other directories)
- branches
- tags
- import

A problem is that I did quite some reorganization on this repository - for example, all the contents of the *pps* directory was once in a subdirectory of *import* (I think I imported it there from CVS), and there may have been other movements, too.

I'm now interested in the contents of the *ltxdoclet* directory together with some other files along the path, like build.xml, the *ant* directory and so on. And I want to have their whole history, including any history before moving the files. And I want it as a git repository now (since I want to publish this on github). The tags and branches were never really used, so they are not important.

I do not want the rest of this repository (they'll get separate git repositories sometimes) - this would blow up my repository too much (and there is some stuff I don't want to publish).

Ideally, my resulting git repository (in the HEAD state) should look like this:

- pps

  - build.xml
  - src

    - ant
    - de

      - dclj

        - paul

          - ltxdoclet

            - (some java files)

I don't really care about historical directory configurations, but the history should not contain any commits who did not touch any of the files in these directories (or their predecessors).

---

Of course, [`git svn`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) seems to be the tool of choice. (Are there others?)

`git svn clone` seems to be the right command ... but with which options? I created an `authors.txt` to convert the CVS or SVN user names to my name and address. To have only the interesting files and directories, I use `--ignore-paths`.

This was my try:

```
filter='^/xcb-src/|_00|src/resources|dclj/faq|dclj/paul/([^l]|l[^t])'
git svn clone svn+ssh://mathe-svn/ --trunk trunk/java/pps -A authors.txt --ignore-paths=$filter latexdoclet
```

Of course, it shows only the history after commit 2306, when I moved `import/java-pps` to `trunk/java/pps` ... and it has lots of commits which have no changes at all.

To solve the first problem, I thought about giving also the old directory as `--trunk`:

```
git svn clone svn+ssh://mathe-svn/ --trunk trunk/java/pps --trunk import/java-pps -A authors.txt --ignore-paths=$filter latexdoclet
```

This does not work, the first `--trunk` is ignored here, and it ends effectively on commit 2305 (before the move). (And it also contains lots of empty commits.)

My current try is to import the whole repository, filtering out anything not wanted:

```
filter='/xcb-src/|_00|src/resources|dclj/faq|dclj/paul/([^l]|l[^t])|/esperanto|finanzen|diverses|homepage|konfig|lua|prog-aufgaben|CVSROOT|latex|tags/'
git svn clone svn+ssh://mathe-svn/ -A authors.txt --ignore-paths=$filter latexdoclet-neu
```

The conversion is still running, but there certainly are lots of commits I don't want at all.

Edit: conversion completed - I now have 2658 commits (3176 objects in git), and only about 36 of them have some interesting tree change, if I configured my gitk filter right. (+ about 3 more which were erroneously filtered out, since our latex source file was first in the `latex` directory.)

---

- Does anyone has better ideas on how to do this?
- Should I better import the whole repository first and then use [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) to pick out the files and commits I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, learn `filter-branch` and do all the edits after the conversion.  You can do it incrementally and reverse each step if you get it wrong.

Comment: Okay, something for tomorrow ... (And I should learn to create questions which have more than simply "Yes" and "no" as answers.) Thanks!

Comment: The whole repository exported to git has 24241 objects, and is about 24 MBs big. So let's see what filtering gives us.

Comment: (For comparison: The SVN repository had 45 MB ... but both have 2658 revisions/commits, so it looks like I have everything.)

Comment: You can't really compare sizes.  git will generally be smaller.  You can count the number of commits with `git rev-list --all | wc -l`, but if you've removed some files and smashed empty commits, you may have fewer.

Comment: After some hours of work (with `filter-branch` I have now only the 40 commits which I really want. (I'll describe this in a separate answer.)

Answer (score 4):

Here what I did, for reference.

---

After the answer from Dustin I first converted the whole svn repository to git, with

```
 git svn clone -A authors.txt svn+ssh://mathe-svn/ all-projects
```

This got me a quite huge git repository of 24241 objects and 24 MBs (after packing), from a git repository of 45 MB. As already said a comment, both had 2658 commits in a linear history, so nothing was lost until now.

Then I started to filter things out ... from the filters offered by [git filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), the `--index-filter` one seemed to be the most useful, since it does not need to checkout anything (compared to `--tree-filter`), and I did not want to rewrite the metadata, only remove unwanted files.

Additionally, `--prune-empty` would be useful, too. I also used `-d /dev/shm/ebermann/git-work/tmp` to put the working directory in a tmpfs, but I don't know if this really mattered, since I did no checkouts here. I used the `--original` option to conserve the original `master` reference under a new name. **(Why doesn't `filter-branch` allow simply creating a new branch and let the old one intact?)**

As my tree-filter, I used `git rm --cached -r --ignore-unmatch`, to which I fed a list of files and directories by `xargs`.

So, I had multiple calls of

```
git filter-branch           \
  -d /dev/shm/ebermann/git-work/tmp  \
   --index-filter "
xargs -a ~/projektoj/git-conversion/remove-liste-5.txt git rm --cached -r --ignore-unmatch 
"        \
   --original "step8"       \
   master
```

and

```
git filter-branch \
  -d  /dev/shm/ebermann/git-work/tmp  \
  --prune-empty \
  --original "step9" \
  master
```

Between, I took a look at the created branch with `gitk`, looking for files I forgot before.
The first file list I created from the output of `svn ls svn+ssh://mathe-svn/path`, removing the files/directories I wanted to retain. I later had to repeat this for older revisions, since some files were renamed (or more exactly, whole directory trees were moved) before, so the old names did not show up. Also, some files were removed before the current revision.

Now I have my `master` branch reduced to 40 revisions, and my HEAD contains 39 files and directories.

The repository (only this branch cloned in a new repository) now is only 180 KB big (with a working tree of 288 KB). I'll now go and clean up the commit comments (which often have nothing at all to do with this project), and then publish it on github.

---

For the next time, **is there some command which creates a list of all file paths which have ever existed in my repository** (without checking all revisions out and for each invoking `find` or such)**?** (Either for git or svn would be okay.)